# An exception was raised while creating "Panel\Authentication\Adapter"; no instance returned

Tags: php, mysql, zend

Fala galera blz, cara to com um erro fd.. no zf2.. (é apenas um sistema para estudo, sei que o framework está desatualizado), o negocio é o seguinte. eu to com 2 modulos, 'Panel', 'Admin' e cada 1 dos modulos se connecta a bancos diferentes. o modulo admin está funcionando normalmente, porém o modulo panel da erro no entitymanager do doctrine. na realidade eu estou com 3 erros.

Erro 1 -

> An exception was raised while creating "Panel\Authentication\Adapter";
>   no instance returned

Erro 2 -

> n exception was raised while creating
>   "doctrine.entitymanager.orm_maxfoodapp"; no instance returned

Erro 3 -

> Options with name "orm_maxfoodapp" could not be found in
>   "doctrine.entitymanager".

Me deem uma luz galera.. ja fiz de tudo e não consigo corrigir isso.

orm.local

```
<?php

return array(
    'doctrine' => array(
        'connection' => array(
            'orm_default' => array(
                'driverClass' => 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver',
                'params' => array(
                    'host' => '127.0.0.1',
                    'port' => '3306',
                    'user' => 'root',
                    'password' => 'root',
                    'dbname' => 'maxfood',
                    'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
                    'driverOptions' => array(
                        1002 => "SET NAMES 'UTF8'"
                    )
                )
            ),

            //////////////////////////////     config-connections -------->
            'orm_maxfoodapp' => array(
                'driverClass' => 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver',
                'params' => array(
                    'host' => 'localhost',
                    'port' => '3306',
                    'user' => 'root',
                    'password' => 'root',
                    'dbname' => 'maxfood_application',
                    'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
                    'driverOptions' => array(
                        1002 => "SET NAMES 'UTF8'"
                    )
                )
            ),
            'configuration' => array(
                //////////////////////////////     config-extra-configuration -------->
                'orm_maxfoodapp' => array(
                    'metadata_cache' => 'array',
                    'query_cache' => 'array',
                    'result_cache' => 'array',
                    'hydration_cache' => 'array',
                    'driver' => 'orm_maxfoodapp',
                    'generate_proxies' => true,
                    'proxy_dir' => 'data/DoctrineORMModule4/Proxy',
                    'proxy_namespace' => 'DoctrineORMModule4\Proxy',
                    'filters' => array()
                ),
            ),
            'entitymanager' => array(
                //////////////////////////////     config-extra-entitymanager -------->
                'orm_maxfoodapp' => array(
                    'connection' => 'orm_maxfoodapp',
                    'configuration' => 'orm_maxfoodapp'
                ),
            ),
            'eventmanager' => array(
                //////////////////////////////     config-extra-eventmanager -------->
                'orm_maxfoodapp' => array(),
            ),
        )
    )
);
```

Adpter -

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: m2corp
 * Date: 29/01/19
 * Time: 09:35
 */

namespace Panel\Authentication;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Zend\Authentication\Adapter\AdapterInterface;
use Zend\Authentication\Result;
use Panel\Entity\Persons;

class Adapter implements AdapterInterface
{

    protected $em;
    protected $username;
    protected $password;

    protected $entity = "Panel\Entity\Persons";

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $username
     */
    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $password
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;
        return $this;
    }



    public function authenticate()
    {
        $repository = $this->em->getRepository($this->entity);
        $user = $repository->username($this->getUsername(),$this->getPassword());

        if($user) {
            return new Result(Result::SUCCESS, array('user' => $user), array('OK'));
        } else {
            return new Result(Result::FAILURE_CREDENTIAL_INVALID, null, array());
        }

    }

}
```

Module -

```
 /**
  * Zend Framework (http://framework.zend.com/)
  *
  * @link      http://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication for the canonical source repository
  * @copyright Copyright (c) 2005-2015 Zend Technologies USA Inc. (http://www.zend.com)
  * @license   http://framework.zend.com/license/new-bsd New BSD License
  */

namespace Panel;

use Zend\Mvc\ModuleRouteListener;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;
use Panel\Authentication\Adapter as AuthAdapter;
use Zend\Authentication\Storage\Session as SessionStorage;
use Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService;

class Module
{
    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        $eventManager        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
        $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
        $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);
    }

    public function getServiceConfig() {

        return array(
            'factories' => array(
                'Panel\Form\Access' => function($sm) {
                    return new Form\Access("access");
                },

                ///////////////////////////////////////////    Serviços   ->
                'Panel\Service\Persons' => function($em) {
                    return new Service\Address($em->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_maxfoodapp'));
                },
                'Panel\Authentication\Adapter' => function($service) {
                    return new AuthAdapter($service->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_maxfoodapp'));
                },
            ),
        );
    }

    public function getViewHelperConfig() {
        return array(
            'factories' => array(
                'flashMessage' => function($sm) {

                    $flashmessenger = $sm->getServiceLocator()
                        ->get('ControllerPluginManager')
                        ->get('flashmessenger');

                    $message   = new \Admin\View\Helper\FlashMessages( ) ;
                    $message->setFlashMessenger( $flashmessenger );

                    return $message ;
                },
            ),
        );
    }

    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
    }

    public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'namespaces' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                ),
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Fala Nando, seria interessante que você formatasse melhor sua pergunta para que os códigos não fiquem cortados ao meio e possamos ler melhor ela como um todo. Outra dica que te dou é melhorar o título da sua pergunta para facilitar pesquisas futuras, dessa forma aí não ajuda muito.

Comment: Fala David, muito obrigado, usava apenas o stack para pesquisa, nunca postei nada, novato é foda haha. mas vlw pelo toque, vou corrigi-los e tomar mais cuidado da próxima vez.. vlww